# DecimalFormat removes preceding zero

Tags: java, floating-point, decimalformat

I am using DecimalFormat to format, 
If the input is 0.0 it removes the preceding zeros. how can I keep the preceding zero's.

My input 0.0 (Float)
Output - .00

The expected output I want is 0.00

```
Float f = Float.parseFloat("0");//f will be 0.0
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.00");
String yourFormattedString = formatter.format(f);//result is .00
```

thanks for your help

Comment: `new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");`

Comment: use can use  formatter.applyLocalizedPattern("#,###,###0.00");

Comment: DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00"); this fixed it thank you both